# Duplicate appdata\local\packages folders

Tags: windows, xamarin, uwp

What is the generated string after the underscore in these appdata packages?

[image]

I ask because my app is suddenly storing a new folder in the Packages folder with the name of my app + '_' + a different random string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the generated string after the underscore in these appdata packages?

It's a computed hash that Windows appends. It's generated from the package and publisher identify information in the application package manifest.

You cannot change or set it directly and your code should not rely on its value.

Comment: So i could have 2 now because of a change to the certificate/key I signed it with, or running it in debug vs release maybe?

Comment: @Chicowitz: If you change the information in the application package manifest, it's no longer the same app as far as Windows is conerned.