# How can I get folder name under AppData/Local/Packages in MAUI?

Tags: c#, .net, maui, .net-maui

I'm making a simple git tool use MAUI.

When I use `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);`

I get `"C:/Users/{MyName}/AppData/Roaming"`.

And then I want to save some file at `Roaming/{MyAppName}/{Files}`;

But Windows will redirects this path to `"C:/Users/{MyName}/AppData/Local/Packages/{GUID}_{hash}/LocalCache/Roaming/{MyAppName}/{Files}"`;

Now, I want to process git to do something with my files in myApp, but I don't kown how to get the redirected path(`Package/{GUID}_{hash}/LocalCache/Roaming`).

The {GUID}_{hash} in my computer is like that `5DDBD798-8CC0-490D-A71B-C2F900533A12_9zz4h110yvjzm`;

I have learned from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55535634/duplicate-appdata-local-packages-folders) that
the hash code is generated from the package and publisher identify information in the application package manifest.I cannot change or set it directly and code should not rely on its value.

So it's obviously not a good solution to hard code the path like what I do now:

```
private string _localRepoPath = "C:/Users/MyName/AppData/Local/Packages/5DDBD798-8CC0-490D-A71B-C2F900533A12_9zz4h110yvjzm/LocalCache/Roaming/MyTool/Files";
```

Summary:

1. How to get {GUID}_{hash} use C# code.
2. I saw many Folders in Packages/ are start with AppName not GUID, how can I use my AppName as the folder name. Like these: `Microsoft.OneDriveSync_8wekyb3d8bbwe  Microsoft.OneDriveSync_8wekyb3d8bbwe  Microsoft.BingWeather_8wekyb3d8bbwe`

Comment: Why they got same hash: 8wekyb3d8bbwe? Hash should be identical.

Comment: yes, if I run the same project on another computer, I will get another completely different hash value. So the hash is identical on different devices.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't figure out your question just now. Actually, I didn't know why their hash is the same as 8wekyb3d8bbwe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the maui, you can try to use the File System Helper instead of the `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);`

```
var path = FileSystem.Current.CacheDirectory;
// the value of path is C:/Users/{MyName}/AppData/Local/Packages/{GUID}_{hash}/LocalCache/

var path = FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory;
// the value of path is C:/Users/{MyName}/AppData/Local/Packages/{GUID}_{hash}/LocalState/
```

For more information, you can check the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/file-system-helpers?tabs=windows).

Comment: The second qusetion, do you know how to use my appName as folderName? Just like `Microsoft.Paint_8wekyb3d8bbwe`. I think it is hard to remember GUID, so it's difficult for me to find files because I have created many MAUI projects.

Comment: I have tried just now. It can't be changed, when I changed the value in the prokect's csproj file, it will show an error. The value of it is set when the project is created. @F_CIL

Comment: Yes, I have tried to change csproj yesterday. I see there are some folders name with AppName like `TelegramMessengerLLP.TelegramDesktop_t4vj0pshhgkwm` in Local/Pacakges/. So I think there must be a way.

Comment: Those folders seems the system folder, not the folder created by the VS when the developer creates  a new project. @F_CIL

Comment: no, not all of them are system folder. I see `Bandisoft.com.15700C60EE320_dytvnjx3s1h08` , Bandzip is an application download form Microsoft store.

Comment: The construct for the application id is [GUID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/guiddef/ns-guiddef-guid), you can try to custom it which is meet the conditions. @F_CIL

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite sure how to deal with it. You say "custom it", do you mean edit ApplicationGUID in csproj? It doesn't take effect.

Comment: Why can't it be done with standard .net System.IO instead of coupling the codebase to .NET Maui. This isn't interoperable for the same app using different frameworks that want to save to the same app data folder